# Add public variable in Rails Model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am trying to pass a manual created variable to my model in Rails.

For example i have a form like this:

```
<%= form_for(@ncpar) do |f| %>
    <%= f.check_box(:corrective_change) %> Change Corrective Action?
    <%= f.text_area :corrective_desc %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

In my database, there is no `corrective_change` column. It is there for the purpose of a manual function in my model which means it will not be save in the database.

In my model, I have putted this:

```
attr_accessor :corrective_change 
#Cause: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: corrective_change
```

I also try:

```
attr_accessible :corrective_change
#Cause: unknown attribute: corrective_change
```

So what should be the way to pass this variable to my model and accessing it?

PS: I could move the code of using `corrective_change` into my controller, but it will ruin my purpose of putting it in Model so I could get it execute automatically whenever it get saved.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is you probably need both:

```
attr_accessor :corrective_change 
attr_accessible :corrective_change
```

these two lines do different things, the first line `attr_accessor` creates a public attribute  on your model with getters and setters.

The second line `attr_accessible` allows you to set this variable via [mass assignment](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#mass-assignment). Basically if you didn't have this line if you do something like this in your controller:

```
@ncpar = NCpar.new(params[:ncpar])
```

If there is a `:corrective_change` in the `params[:ncpar]` it will be ignored for security reasons unless you explicitly state that you want to allow that variable to be set via mass assignment with:

```
attr_accessible :corrective_change
```

Answer (score 0):

`attr_accessor` is what you want.  You just don't want it to be protected.  Try moving the `attr_accessor` directive above the `protected` line in your model.

Comment: can you give me details? My ActiveRecord class does not have the `protected` modifier

Comment: Darn that would have been too easy, eh.  I'll keep thinking about it... sorry.

Comment: Ok ^^. Im still trying to figure out. Apparently, adding `attr_accessor :corrective_change` follow by `attr_accessible :corrective_change` seem to fix the issue but I am still checking if it is really pass to the model or not.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, adding

```
attr_accessor :corrective_change 
attr_accessible :corrective_change
```

Seem to fix the issue.

Underlying problem i think the `attr_accessor` create getters and setter, but private. However the `attr_accessible` makes the value become publicly accessible.